# Fitting a polynomial with numpy changes with dtype, even though actual data values remain the same

Tags: python, numpy, polynomials, non-linear-regression

I have a dataset comprised of `xdata` and `ydata` that I want to fit a polynomial to, but for some reason, the fitting results depend on the `dtype` of the dataset, even though the actual values of the data remain *unchanged*. I understand that if you change the `dtype` e.g. from `float` to `int`, that there can be some loss of information, but in this case I am converting from `'f4'` to `'f8'`, thus no information is lost, which is why I am at a loss. What is going on here?

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.polynomial import polynomial

x32 = np.array([
    1892.8972, 1893.1168, 1893.1626, 1893.4313, 1893.4929, 1895.6392,
    1895.7642, 1896.4286, 1896.5693, 1897.313,  1898.4648
], dtype='f4')

y32 = np.array([
    510.83655, 489.91592, 486.4508,  469.21814, 465.7902,  388.65576,
    385.37637, 369.07236, 365.8301,  349.7118,  327.4062
], dtype='f4')

x64 = x32.astype('f8')
y64 = y32.astype('f8')

a, residuals1, _, _, _ = np.polyfit(x32, y32, 2, full=True)
b, residuals2, _, _, _ = np.polyfit(x64, y64, 2, full=True)

c, (residuals3, _, _, _) = polynomial.polyfit(x32, y32, 2, full=True)
d, (residuals4, _, _, _) = polynomial.polyfit(x64, y64, 2, full=True)

print(residuals1, residuals2, residuals3, residuals4)  # [] [195.86309188] [] [195.86309157]
print(a)        # [ 3.54575804e+00 -1.34738721e+04  1.28004924e+07]
print(b)        # [-8.70836523e-03  7.50419309e-02  3.15525483e+04]
print(c[::-1])  # [ 3.54575804e+00 -1.34738721e+04  1.28004924e+07]
print(d[::-1])  # [-8.7083541e-03   7.5099051e-02   3.1552398e+04 ]
```

I also only noticed this issue because I'm also interested in the residuals values and they turned up to be empty, which caused my program to crash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This differing behaviour is due to `rcond` in [`polynomial`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.20.0/numpy/lib/polynomial.py#L453-L689), which is precision-dependent:

```
    rcond : float, optional
        Relative condition number of the fit. Singular values smaller than
        this relative to the largest singular value will be ignored. The
        default value is len(x)*eps, where eps is the relative precision of
        the float type, about 2e-16 in most cases.

...

    # set rcond
    if rcond is None:
        rcond = len(x)*finfo(x.dtype).eps
```

Setting `rcond` to an appropriately small value for the 32bit example will produce the same results as the 64bit one (e.g. `rcond=1e-7` or smaller) .

Comment: Thanks! If only I studied the documentation more thoroughly, though still I would have probably never guessed this to be the reason. Good to know that this parameter can occasionally really be something to look out for.

Answer (score 1):

The difference happens due to `rcond` hidden parameter of [polyfit()](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.polyfit.html) being different for float32 and float64. This is relative error of approximation. For float32 its default is around 2e-7, for float64 its default is around 2e-16. If you specify same rcond param by yourself then you'll get same results.

Code below uses `rcond` param and also draws plots using `np.polyval` to show almost same visual results.

[Try it online!](https://replit.com/@moytrage/StackOverflow66969023#main.py)

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.polynomial import polynomial
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x32 = np.array([
    1892.8972, 1893.1168, 1893.1626, 1893.4313, 1893.4929, 1895.6392,
    1895.7642, 1896.4286, 1896.5693, 1897.313,  1898.4648
], dtype = 'f4')

y32 = np.array([
    510.83655, 489.91592, 486.4508,  469.21814, 465.7902,  388.65576,
    385.37637, 369.07236, 365.8301,  349.7118,  327.4062
], dtype = 'f4')

x64 = x32.astype('f8')
y64 = y32.astype('f8')

rcond = 2e-7

a, residuals1, _, _, _ = np.polyfit(x32, y32, 2, full=True, rcond = rcond)
b, residuals2, _, _, _ = np.polyfit(x64, y64, 2, full=True, rcond = rcond)

c, (residuals3, _, _, _) = polynomial.polyfit(x32, y32, 2, full=True, rcond = rcond)
d, (residuals4, _, _, _) = polynomial.polyfit(x64, y64, 2, full=True, rcond = rcond)

print(residuals1, residuals2, residuals3, residuals4)  
# [] [195.86309188] [] [195.86309157]
print(a)  # [ 3.54575804e+00 -1.34738721e+04  1.28004924e+07]
print(b)  # [-8.70836523e-03  7.50419309e-02  3.15525483e+04]
print(c)  # [ 1.28004924e+07 -1.34738721e+04  3.54575804e+00]
print(d)  # [ 3.1552398e+04  7.5099051e-02 -8.7083541e-03]

plt.plot(x64, y64, label = 'orig')
plt.plot(x32, np.polyval(a, x32), label = 'x32_v0')
plt.plot(x64, np.polyval(b, x64), label = 'x64_v0')
plt.plot(x32, np.polyval(c[::-1], x32), label = 'x32_v1')
plt.plot(x64, np.polyval(d[::-1], x64), label = 'x64_v1')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I would have never guessed this to be the cause. Good to know the visuals line up.